# SSMS generate script of all DB including partition functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms, database-partitioning

I am trying to generate script from SSMS for all my DB but the **partition functions** doesn't appear in the generated script.

Does anybody know how to include them into the script ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't specify exactly how you're generating your creation scripts (SSMS GUI, T-SQL or some other way), but [this existing question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171365/how-to-generate-the-creation-script-for-partition-function-and-partition-schema) may help.

Comment: That's correct ! I use the GUI Task/generate script and the partition scheme option is set to True ;)